# Predef.readLine behaviour

Tags: scala, console

```
scala> val input = readLine("hello %s%n", "world")
hello WrappedArray(world)
input: String = ""

scala> val input = Console.readLine("hello %s%n", "world")
hello world
input: String = ""
```

What's the reason for the difference here? (I tried it compiled as well, so it's not a REPL thing.)

Scala version 2.9.0-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like a bug in `Predef`:

```
def readLine(text: String, args: Any*) = Console.readLine(text, args)
```

When I think it should be:

```
def readLine(text: String, args: Any*) = Console.readLine(text, args: _*)
```

The first version you use is calling `Prefef.readLine`. Because of the missing `_*` type ascription, the function is called with `args` as the single first argument of the repeated argument `args` of `Console.readLine`.

In the *uncurry* compilation phase, this single argument is wrapped into a `WrappedArray` so that it it can be treated as a `Seq[Any]`. The `WrappedArray` is then converted using the `toString` method and this is what is used for `%s` in `"hello %s%n"`. I think that is what happens.

In the second version `args` is treated from the start as a `Seq[Any]` and no conversion happens.

The whole thing is a bit funny, because in general the compiler does not let you do this:

```
scala> def f(s: Int*) = s foreach println
f: (s: Int*)Unit

scala> def g(s: Int*) = f(s)
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int*
 required: Int
       def g(s: Int*) = f(s)
```

With `Any`, you get past the typer phase.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral, here you go: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5066. I wonder where the `WrappedArray` comes from, though.

Comment: That one is easy. A varargs is usually passed as a WrappedArray. Since "args" was passed as a single argument, then WrappedArray is passed as argument.